# How to create two level context menu in autodesk forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge, autodesk-viewer

I want to creat two level context menu but there is no api for this.Just look like this
[level context menu image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6LFu.png)
what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

It is rather straighforward to acheive a multi level context menu by deriving from `Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ObjectContextMenu`. Simply provide an array in the `target` field:

```
buildMenu (event, node) {

  var menu = []

  switch (node.type) {

    case 'hubs':

      menu.push({
        title: 'Show details',
        className: 'fa fa-share',
        target: [{
          title: 'Hub details',
          className: 'fa fa-cloud',
          target: () => {
            this.emit('context.details', {
              event, node, type: 'hubs'
            })
          }
        }, {
          title: 'Projects details',
          className: 'fa fa-folder',
          target: () => {
            this.emit('context.details', {
              event, node, type: 'hubs.projects'
            })
          }
        }]
      })

      break
```

[image]

A complete example of this can be found here: [DataContextMenu.js](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-boilers.nodejs/blob/master/6%20-%20viewer%2Bserver%2Bdata-mng%2Bderivatives/src/client/components/DataManagement/DataPanel/DataContextMenu.js)

Comment: Thank you,This method can build a two level menu.But how to trigger the two level menu with hover event，It is not very useful to trigger a secondary menu with a click event

Comment: Well, you could either derive your own ContextMenu and implement a custom behavior, look the methods ContextMenu.prototype.addCallbackToMenuItem and ContextMenu.prototype.addSubmenuCallbackToMenuItem in viewer3D.js where the click event is implemented. Use a mouseover event instead. Or as suggested by Eason previously, implement from scratch your own menu or use of of the many available open source library for that. Unfortunately I cannot recommend you a specific one.

Comment: Thank you very much.I  changed several functions of viewer3D.js in your way.It works well

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not available on current viewer version. You might have to write your own context menu in deep. But there is a workaround that you can follow:

1. Override functions of `Autodesk.Viewing.Private.ContextMenu` to provide multiple level menus.
2. Refer codes from `Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ObjectContextMenu`, then create your owned `ObjectContextMenu` and replace `contextMenu` property with the your owned multiple levels `ContextMenu` from the step 1.
3. Refer codes from `Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.ViewerObjectContextMenu`, then write your owned `ViewerObjectContextMenu` that inherits the custom  `ObjectContextMenu` from the step 2.

**P.S. This is just a workaround, it's not the formal solution, you might have to use it at your own risk.**